# PHP preg_split. Can't find or figure out ex for this

Tags: php, json, regex, grep, preg-split

I did try but can't find or figure out regex for the following

Working in PHP need preg_split to work

```
{password=123456, telephone=9452979342}/{Accept=application/json, Authorization=Bearer kadaljdlkadjsdaskdjaskdasdf}
```

What I want is to split this string into array like this:

1. Split by '/' in middle

   ```
   [0] => {password=123456, telephone=9452979342}

   [2] => {Accept=application/json, Authorization=Bearer kadaljdlkadjsdaskdjaskdasdf}
   ```
2. Select between {*}

   ```
   [0] => password=123456, telephone=9452979342

   [2] => Accept=application/json, Authorization=Bearer kadaljdlkadjsdaskdjaskdasdf
   ```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your way , you may try the following approach as well

```
$re = '/\}\/\{/m';
$str = '{password=123456, telephone=9452979342}/{Accept=application/json, Authorization=Bearer kadaljdlkadjsdaskdjaskdasdf}';
$arr=preg_split($re,$str);
$cnt=0;
foreach($arr as $values)
 $arr[$cnt++]=preg_replace('/[{}]/','',$values);
 print_r($arr);
```

[run here](https://ideone.com/E3m0gt)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want:

```
$str = "{password=123456, telephone=9452979342}/{Accept=application/json, Authorization=Bearer kadaljdlkadjsdaskdjaskdasdf}";
preg_match('~\{(.+?)\}/\{(.+?)\}~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => {password=123456, telephone=9452979342}/{Accept=application/json, Authorization=Bearer kadaljdlkadjsdaskdjaskdasdf}
    [1] => password=123456, telephone=9452979342
    [2] => Accept=application/json, Authorization=Bearer kadaljdlkadjsdaskdjaskdasdf
)
```

Comment: Looks like right, just like i want but can you make it so it only outputs ele 1 and 2 no need for ele 1

Comment: @JaspreetSingh: Element `0` represents the whole match, it is always present. You can do an `array_shift` to remove it from the array.